# MYSQL Update (change) many fields together

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i have a table with a number of fields, some INT and some VARCHAR.

The problem is that, due to certain problems in importing, certain feilds have been assigned VARCHAR 20 and VARCHAR 10 etc. However, the data it would contain is longer than a hundred characters.

Is there a way, in mysql, to make **all** VARCHAR fields as VARCHAR 300 in place of VARCHAR 20 etc.., with a single query

Instead of this:

```
Field 1 : VARCHAR 15
Field 2 : VARCHAR 20
Field 3 : INT 6
```

I want

```
Field 1 : VARCHAR 300
Field 2 : VARCHAR 300
Field 3 : INT 6
```

Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: Why was  i downvoted :-( i didn't find an answer anywhere else for this

Comment: You are downvoted because you are losing ten times more time looking for a single query instead of just changing one by one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ALTER TABLE` statement to modify your columns:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
    MODIFY COLUMN Field1 VARCHAR(300),
    MODIFY COLUMN Field2 VARCHAR(300),
...
    MODIFY COLUMN FieldN VARCHAR(300);
```

Another way is to use a procedure to get all tables and update all fields. But I think it's not your situation here.

Comment: _Is there a way, in mysql, to make all VARCHAR fields as VARCHAR 300 in place of VARCHAR 20 etc..,_ **with a single query**.

Comment: @RahulSharma Than they should run this query using `msqli` - what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: @RahulSharma . . . "Yes", you alter the column to be the correct length.  You have to list the columns.  The only shortcoming to this answer is that Felippe repeated that `alter table` instead of doing multiple modifications in one statement.  But the idea is correct.

Comment: Edited, just use comma instead.

Comment: Can we do it in one single query, I've got over 80 feilds?

Comment: Yes you can. I've made with 100 for testing purposes.

Comment: @RahulSharma it's one query now.